# Designing a responsive layout with Bootsrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

I want to have a page with the following responsive layout:

[Image 1) A responsive page layout with 3 boxes (on small/medium screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5YRH.png)

[Image 2) A responsive page layout with 3 boxes (on wide screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqOxx.png)

The goal is to make this page responsive so that whenever screen is too wide, box 3 will jump next to box 2 (like image 2). For this I use grid system of Bootstrap with allocating "8" spans for Box 1 and "4" for box 2 and 3. It works the way I described. Now I want to fix the position of Box 2 and Box 3 so when I scroll the page (to see the content of Box 1) I will see Box 2 and 3 in my viewport and I don't want to make Box 1 scrollable! I want the whole page to scroll! Do you know any Bootstrap solution that will handle this situation? (I want to keep the responsive layout of the whole page)

This is the basic code that I have for the page:

```html
<div class=row>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6">Box 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">Box 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Right now I can make Box 1 scrollable but it will put the scrollbar next to box 1, but I want it to be at the right side of the page, so the whole page scrolls but box 2 and 3 are fixed. And at the same time, on large screens they will change their position and all 3 boxes will be next to each other!

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: can you explain a bit :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic My responsive layout works fine but I'm not able to scroll the page and fix box 2 and 3. If I fix them on the page the design is not responsive anymore. Is there a Bootstrap solution that will fix box 2 and 3 (while scrolling the whole page) but at the same time responsive so whenever the screen is wide, box 2 and 3 are next to each other?

Comment: so when screen is small you want them one on top of another, and when screen is small you want them one by another ?

Comment: @MarkoMackic Yes! So on small/medium screen I want them to be like the figure in the attached image in the main post, and in wide screen I want box 3 to jump next to the box 2. My sample code snippet works like this, the problem is that I can't fix box 2 and 3 (if I do, layout is not responsive anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FIXED

If i got you right :) Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fL2L0qnj/2/ , just resize the result area to see effect :)

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
<div class="box0"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12"> <!--do this at your preference, look at example and then
 arrange it for your self :)

<div class="box1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
<div class="box2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box1,.box2{
  width:80%;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px auto;
}
.box0{
  width:80%;
  height:220px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:10px;

  background:green;
}
.box1{
    background:blue;
}
.box2{
  background:red;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(".keeptop").offset().top;
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY > y) {
        var padY = scrollY - y;
        $(".keeptop").css("padding-top", padY);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Marko, I updated the main post with the image of page layout on both small and wide screens, I achieved this layout with the included code snippet but the problem is with scrolling the whole page while box 2 and 3 are fixed! Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: i'll fix it in a second :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, it looks like the layout I want but the main problem is still there! Change "height" in .box0 from 220px to 820px and scroll the page, in this case I want to be able to see blue and red box as a fixed element on page (and I don't want to only make the green box scrollable, I want the whole page to scroll) any ideas?

Comment: in the layout that you have right now, imagine that the green box is big that you have to scroll the page to see rest of it (you can do it by changing its hight to 820px for example). Now when you scroll the page, you no longer see the blue and red box (they scroll with the page). But I want them to be fixed on page so I see them all the time while scrolling the page (to see the rest of green box). If I use "position: fixed;" in stylesheet for red and blue box the design is not responsive anymore (to switch between medium/large screen), so I wanna know how to handle this...

Comment: i get you :) :) wait a bit :)